# After run Eclipse Product export wizard, I couldn't see exe file on exported\eclipse folder

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

First time when I exported Plug-in project by Eclipse Product export wizard, I got exe & ini file on eclipse folder. I had some trouble so I re-created new Plug-in project and product configuration file than clicked Eclipse Product export wizard. After that I checked created folder, it doesn't including exe & ini file.

How to create an exe file?

Comment: I removed some sentences that did not really add anything to the question (like thanks, or "It's strange").

Answer (score 3):

Possible solutions to try

1. Make sure you do not select "generate metadata repository" unless u need p2 site update to your product.
2. Make sure your "application plug in ID" and "Product ID" do not clash. If yes, selecting 1st option would fail to generate exe.
3. Make sure you added "org.eclipse.rcp " in your product dependencies.
4. Check whether you have selected "The product
   includes native launcher artifacts" in your product file. You will find this option in your overview tab.

Let me know if these doesn't solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: the second was issued in my case. After changed the product id, I could create the exe file. Thank you for your helping

Comment: Fourth was my issue. Strange that my first time exporting a product it was selected, and it became unselected when I went to go export again. I also didn't see the connect between 'native launcher artifacts' and the executable, although knowing what it is now, I see how they're connected. As someone learning PDE though, that wasn't obvious to me since it's on the Overview tab. It definitely should be on the 'Launching' tab for PDE (where the rest of the launcher options are); whoever put it on the Overview tab needs a lesson in UI management.